# Conditional uniform distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

I had this question in a quiz, and now that I am reviewing it, I am not sure if why my TA gave me the marks because I am pretty sure I am wrong.

Let the r.v. $Y$ follow uniform distribution $U(1,2)$

Find $P(Y > 1.5 | 1.2 < Y < 1.6)$

My attempt:

$\frac{P(Y > 1.5 \cap 1.2 < Y < 1.6)}{P(1.2 < Y < 1.6)}$

$=\frac{P(1.5 < Y < 1.6)}{P(1.2 < Y < 1.6)}$

$=\frac{0.1}{0.4}$

$=\frac{1}{4}$

Have I got it right and my TA is just trying to boost the marks of the class or was my original answer (below) correct:

$=\frac{P(1.2 < Y < 1.6)}{P(Y > 1.5)}$

$=\frac{0.4}{0.5}$

$=\frac{4}{5}$

Comment: You have got it right in your attempt. Not in your original answer.

Comment: I am confused then, seems all of my quiz answers are marked as 100% despite everything being wrong!!